# Setting flow to road network using Utility Network Analyst of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, utility-network

I'm editing the freeway network of the Lisbon Metropolitan Area for 2013. Currently, I am trying to establish the flows of the freeways and their accesses using the Utility Network Analyst but I can't do it.
The button 'Set Flow Direction' (brown color on picture below) is OFF despite the Utility Network Analyst is ON (blue trace) and the editor ON (green trace).

Important to say I used the tool 'Set Flow Direction' from Data Managements Tools to give me a pre-defined flow. In this case is the inversus of digitalization. Either way, if I don't set before all the network will be with undetermined flows which I also cannot change.

What can I do to set the flows?

[image: Example 1]

Comment: Utility network analyst is designed more for utilities (gas, electric, water) and can struggle a bit with roads, particularly as there can be loops in roads.  Flow direction won't set unless you're able to force it (unsure if you can without additional tools) because it doesn't know how to treat the loops.  Do you have access to Network Analyst extension?

Comment: Yes, I have access to Network Analyst. I also used topology to search for possible errors.

Comment: I went to the simbology and after some modifications it was possible to see that my flows are after all uninitialized. Went to ESRI support [link](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000006589) and checked that all my values are true. In the end they state to run the Find Path trace task but have the same problem as before: this kind of analysis is OFF.

Comment: [Network Analyst](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/networkanalyst) is far better suited for road networks than the [Utility Network Analyst (Geometric Networks)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geometric-networks/what-are-geometric-networks-.htm)

Comment: Agree but how can I set the flows in the Network Analyst?

Comment: Network Analyst allows the setting of traffic directions using attributes.  I suggest you convert a sample area into a Network (you'll need to remove it from your geometric network) and read up about Networks.  Ask a new question if/when you get stuck on that.